How to print math inside a gt() table in Quarto
I'm writing a Quarto document. I'd like to have math inside a gt() table. How do I do that? Here is a sample document. The math inside the gt() table does not render:
Euler's identity: $e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0$.

```{r}
#| echo: false
library(gt)

data.frame(
  Formula = "$e^{i \\pi} + 1 = 0$"
  , Name = "Euler's identity"
) |> gt()
```


gt package has fmt_markdown() function that renders markdown text. Try data.frame(...) |> gt() |> fmt_markdown()

These 2 approaches work:
```{r}
library(gt)  
data.frame(Formula = "Wonderful: $e^{i \\pi} + 1 = 0$", Name = "Euler's identity" ) |> 
  gt()|> 
  fmt_markdown()
```

```{r}
library(gt)  
data.frame(Formula = "$$e^{i \\pi} + 1 = 0$$", Name = "Euler's identity" ) |> 
  gt()
```

